# Validate a username against a remote Active Directory

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory

I've been given a task to take a username and check to see if it exists in an Azure-hosted Active Directory. The context where this is happening is a .NET web service that acts as the server in a client/server system.

Unfortunately, I have almost no expertise in this area.

What I have is some code from the client application that creates a class called PublicClientApplication using some string values read from a json file. I was able to put the json file into the .NET application, read it, and create the PublicClientApplication successfully.

There is a function called GetAccountAsync(string accountId). I tried it, but it didn't return any result, even when I'm sure that the string I'm passing in is the correct account name (or at least, the same name that the user typed to log in).

The documentation for GetAccountAsync says "The identifier is typically the value of the Identifier property of AccountId. You typically get the account id from an IAccount by using the HomeAccountId property". I'm guessing that this is not the same as the account name, but I don't know where to get it. I have a jwt token, which is where I get the account name, but it doesn't appear to contain any kind of ID.

Furthermore, I also tried calling GetAccountsAsync(), which is supposed to return all accounts, but I got an empty list.

What can I do to make this work?

Frank

Comment: Is your app a public client application? I mean, does it run on the user's device? Do you need to get the info before the user has authenticated?

Comment: The client runs on the user's device, the server runs on my device. The purpose of this is not to authenticate the user but to ensure that they still exist in Active Directory if a lot of time has passed since they were originally authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially to check for the existence of a user, you will need to call Microsoft Graph API. There are 2 ways to do so: 1) using scopes/delegated permissions on behalf of the user, 2) using application permissions as the app.

Option 1 requires you to authenticate the user first, so that wouldn't really work in your case.

Option 2 you cannot do from the public client app, since it requires usage of a secret. You could do it with an endpoint in your back-end that doesn't require authentication. The problem with that is that it'll enable account enumeration by malicious parties.

Personally, I wouldn't do a check like this. The user would get an error on the login page anyway if their account is locked etc. (or your app will receive an error in its callback URL)

Comment: Thanks for the notes. My customer's concern is that the user is able to log in because their account is active, but then their account is deactivated at some point while they are using the app. In this case the JWT token will still be valid and the user would be able to keep using the application until it expired. The customer wants to ensure that the application stops working immediately.